# More columns for badges in narrow width mode

Tags: feature-request, design, badges, responsive-design

It seems that badges could be displayed in more columns in narrow width mode. Tested on my iPad.

Below the screenshots to compare:

- full width

> [image: full width]

- 3/4 width

> [image: 3/4 width]

- half width

> [image: half width]

- quarter width

> [image: quarter]

At least one more column can fit in half and quarter width views. Could we please use empty page space more rationally?